# Trying to parse through a large JSON object and extract data, but keep getting unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, json

I have a file, sample.JSON with the following contents:

```
{   "resultset": {
    "-count": "4904",
    "-resultType": "campgrounds",
    "result": [
      {
        "-availabilityStatus": "N",
        "-contractID": "GA",
        "-contractType": "STATE",
        "-facilityID": "530145",
        "-facilityName": "A. H. STEPHENS STATE HISTORIC PARK",
        "-faciltyPhoto": "/webphotos/GA/pid530145/0/80x53.jpg",
        "-latitude": "33.5633333",
        "-longitude": "-82.8966667",
        "-shortName": "C145",
        "-sitesWithAmps": "Y",
        "-sitesWithPetsAllowed": "Y",
        "-sitesWithSewerHookup": "N",
        "-sitesWithWaterHookup": "Y",
        "-state": "GA"
      },
      {
        "-availabilityStatus": "N",
        "-contractID": "OH",
        "-contractType": "STATE",
        "-facilityID": "960023",
        "-facilityName": "A.W. MARION STATE PARK",
        "-faciltyPhoto": "/webphotos/OH/pid960023/0/80x53.jpg",
        "-latitude": "39.6336111",
        "-longitude": "-82.8747222",
        "-shortName": "P023",
        "-sitesWithAmps": "Y",
        "-sitesWithPetsAllowed": "Y",
        "-sitesWithSewerHookup": "N",
        "-sitesWithWaterHookup": "N",
        "-state": "OH"
      },
      {
        "-availabilityStatus": "N",
        "-contractID": "NRSO",
        "-contractType": "FEDERAL",
        "-facilityID": "72346",
        "-facilityName": "ACKER ROCK LOOKOUT",
        "-faciltyPhoto": "/webphotos/NRSO/pid72346/0/80x53.jpg",
        "-latitude": "43.0523056",
        "-longitude": "-122.6456111",
        "-shortName": "ARCL",
        "-sitesWithAmps": "N",
        "-sitesWithPetsAllowed": "Y",
        "-sitesWithSewerHookup": "N",
        "-sitesWithWaterHookup": "N",
        "-state": "OR"
      }
    ]   } }
```

This is just a sample of a much larger JSON object that I would like to go through and select out the facilityName from each array object (not sure if that's the right term), and then write each facilityName to a new file.

I know I need to load the JSON object, and then do a for loop for the length of the object. Right now I'm just trying to get the sample.JSON file to load. Here is my code so far:

```
var data = require('./campSample.JSON');
var fs = require('fs');

console.log(JSON.parse(data));
```

Trying to run this with node keeps giving me SyntaxError: Unexpected token :, referring to the colon in "resultset": {

I don't know why this would be. I used a JSON validator to confirm that the JSON is good. Why is it telling me that this syntax is wrong?

Comment: What JSON validator did you use?

Answer (score 1):

`require()` already parses your JSON.

You don't need to do anything.

Comment: But even doing just console.log(data); gives me the same error.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: How could `console.log(data)` possibly give you a JSON parsing error?

Answer (score 1):

Change `.JSON` in the filename to be lowercase.

`require()` has [special code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L430) to parse `.json` files as JSON rather than Javascript, but this is case-sensitive.

Comment: Ah ha! This did it. Thanks!